# Send email by trigger when a new row is inserted into a specific table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, email, triggers

Im looking for ways to automate some processes and I need to create a trigger whenever a new row is added on an specific table.

This trigger has to send an email with a template to the new mail in the Email column of the table. Is there a way to do that?
How?

I tried using some postgreSQL triggers but it is not enough. I expect to send a mail to the specific Email and send some other information that would be contained in the new row in the specific table.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help with your issues, but there are certain expectations on you. Please spend a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. 
 Then update your question to include sample data, table definition (ddl scripts), the expected results of that data and what you have tried, all as text - **no images**; also adding a  [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) is extremely useful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.